# 301 redirect on new domain without trailing / slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I would like to redirect all url's from domain:

> http://exampledomain.com

to new domain on specyfic address which works only without trailing slash on the end of address

> http://www.newdomain.com/123-content

I tried many rules in .htaccess, but everytime it redirects to url with / on the end and it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following rules at `.htaccess` in oldsite main root :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)([^/]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^    http://newdomain.com%1%2  [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: glad to help , Thanks