# Small redirect chain after domain migration due to trailing slashes. How do I fix it? (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, url, dns

so I've changed the domain address of a website, and now I'm facing a small redirect chain due to trailing slashes.

https://olddomain.com/ first redirects to https://newdomain.com/ and then to https://newdomain.com   (the version without the trailing slash)

I need https://olddomain.com/ to directly redirect to https://newdomain.com

This is the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "and then to `https://newdomain.com`" - Check the network traffic. There is no external redirect here - they are the same URL! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885220/htaccess-add-trailing-slash-to-root

Comment: Well, Google considers it as two separate URLs. I did a domain change recently, and I redirected every link from the old domain to the new domain. All my links are without trailing slashes, hence the versions of the URLs ending with "/" redirects to the versions of the URL without "/". After the domain change, Google starts to recrawl every link on the old domain, including those ending with "/", and since they first redirect to newdomain.com/ and then to newdomain.com, Google sees it as an additional redirect and waste the crawling budget on it. So I need to fix it.

Comment: This is the redirect chain I'm talking about: https://ibb.co/9NBDwHn

Comment: But that can hardly be caused by the rule you have shown us, even if `$1` was empty, `https://newdomain.com/$1` would still leave `https://newdomain.com/`

Comment: Hi CBroe, yes, but I need those rules to redirect the links from the old domain directly to the new domain without trailing slash. Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506399/301-redirect-on-new-domain-without-trailing-slash, but this one didn't worked for me.

Comment: You need to find out where this erroneous 2nd "redirect"(?) is coming from. It makes no sense to modify your existing rule to omit the trailing slash after the hostname (at the _start_ of the URL-path) on requests to the root only, since any compliant user-agent (browser, spider or search engine bot) must then "correct" the redirected request to _include_ the trailing slash. (You can observe this behaviour if you monitor the network traffic in the browser.)

Comment: A request for `https://example.com` (no trailing slash after the hostname) is not strictly a valid HTTP request. You cannot have an entirely empty URL-path. When you type `https://example.com` in the browser (or issue a redirect to this URL), the browser actually "corrects" this silently and effectively appends the trailing slash. You can see this in the first line of the HTTP request headers, which would look something like `GET / HTTP/1.1` in both cases. Identical for both requests. (This is as per [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2))

Comment: With regards to SEO, Google does _not_ differentiate those URLs that omit the trailing slash (after the hostname) and those that include it when it comes to actually indexing the URLs. However, the doctored screenshot you've posted does not appear to make sense. What you have in the "Path" column is presumably the "Host" and the "Host" column is not valid?

Comment: Thank you for your input MrWhite. I have no idea where the 2nd redirects come from. I thought this could be fixed with a new rule in .htaccess.  Can't a rule "dictate" the user-agent to directly visit the version without trailing slashes on the new domain without being necessary to first visit the / version? If the request comes from https://olddomain.com/random-page (without trailing slash), it redirects to https://newdomain.com/random-page. Which is what I want. But I also want https://olddomain.com/random-page(/) to redirect to the same URL without trailing slash on the new domain.

Comment: Thank you lots for your support on this MrWhite. Regarding SEO, I'm not worried about indexing stuff but rather about wasting the crawling budget to crawl those URLs ending with / which redirect to the non-/ version. Regarding the screenshot, under the host is shown the domain name (which I wanted to hide). The first column includes https://olddomain.com(/), the second https://newdomain.com(/), and the third https://newdomain.com. The redirect "chain" I was talking about.